# What is the purpose of the foreach tag?

Tags: support, tags

The [foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foreach) tag. I've never used it, but I see it pop up in a lot of questions that have nothing even remotely do with the `foreach` loop. Even though they may contain the code. It's very rarely the actual subject of the question.

Why would I use this tag and when?

For example, this question: [Insert jQuery Calender in a "Foreach" Statement Gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681685/insert-jquery-calender-in-a-foreach-statement-gridview)

The subject is not the `foreach` loop, but the `jQuery` date picker. Is it still applicable to tag this with [foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foreach)?

Comment: Tags are often misused. This should probably be a request to have the tag cleaned up, with a few examples of misuse provided.

Comment: @Dukeling I'm not sure if they do constitute misuse though. Personally I do, but I'm not sure if that's the general consensus. I've added an example of what I'm talking about.

Comment: I figured you were talking about something more like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22618968/loop-through-all-the-rows-of-a-temp-table-and-call-a-stored-procedure-for-each-r).

Comment: @Dukeling That's probably one I would nail down to *definitely not* requiring a foreach tag. Just seems like an odd thing to tag a question with.

Comment: I don't think foreach requires a tag. Does every programming construct within a language (or even a language-agnostic construct) need a tag of its own? I'd say remove the tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the code in the question *contains* some construct, but the question isn't directly *about* it, it shouldn't contain the tag associated with it.

Although I usually view removing it as a minor edit, perhaps incorrectly so, and whether or not a question is actually about a construct is perhaps arguable in some cases.

I could be wrong, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22664445/how-can-sto-foreach-an-div-class-in-smarty2-template) seems like a decent use of the [foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foreach) tag - it's specifically about trying to break from a foreach loop.

---

You could take another stance saying that any question which requires familiarity with something should have the associated tag, but then there's basically no point to having any of the following tags (to name a few): [foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foreach), [methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/methods), [class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/class), [for-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/for-loop), [while-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/while-loop), [break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/break), [continue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/continue), [do-while](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/do-while), as many questions require familiarity with many such constructs, while a question can only have 5 tags, and it would be next to impossible to identify a question actually *about* one of these constructs (such questions would be my main argument for not getting rid of the above tags).

Comment: there is no point at all in having any of the tags foreach, for-loop, while-loop, break, continue, do-while.  they all just fall under control flow or "programming" or the language in question.